# Write registers data into array using asm C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I created a program that writes registers data into variables using asm. And it seems to be working well. But then I decided to replace variables by an array and to write registers data into an array. I used the same approach, but noticed that when I'm printing variables and array members they have different values, but should have the same values.
What I'm doing wrong trying to write the registers values into an array? As I understand it 
should work the same way if to write to a standalone variable.

```
void read_registers(void)
{
    int ebx_val, ecx_val, edx_val;
    char reg_name[4][4] = {"ebx", "ecx", "edx"};
    int reg_val[3];

    printk("\n===OLD VALUES BELOW===");
    test_syscall();/*inside of the syscall registers were written 0xDEADBEEF*/
    __asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%ebx,%0" : "=r"(ebx_val));
    __asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%ecx,%0" : "=r"(ecx_val));
    __asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%edx,%0" : "=r"(edx_val));

    printk("\nReg ebx val user mode 0x%x\n", ebx_val);
    printk("\nReg ecx val user mode 0x%x\n", ecx_val);
    printk("\nReg edx val user mode 0x%x\n", edx_val);

    printk("\n===NEW VALUES BELOW===");

    __asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%ebx,%0" : "=r"(reg_val[0]));
    __asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%ecx,%0" : "=r"(reg_val[1]));
    __asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%edx,%0" : "=r"(reg_val[2]));
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    printk("\nReg %s val is 0x%x\n", reg_name + i,
            reg_val[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think they would have the same values? You have a couple of `printk` in between so no telling how the registers changed. Also, the `r` constraint may pick whatever register it wants so maybe it stored your `ebx` into `ecx`. Using a `mov` is unnecessary anyway. Furthermore the array access might use a register too.

Comment: There's no reason to expect them to have the same values.  The code generated by the compiler is free to do as it likes with `%ebx, %ecx, %edx` in between your calls, since you have not told it otherwise.  In particular, those registers are almost certainly overwritten by `printk`.  Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: I'm doing that to check registers state after system call. During the system call, I wrote into registers 0xDEADBEEF data, then when returning from system call, I check registers, they should not have 0xDEADBEEF data.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that looks like a system call.  But if that's what you want, the correct approach is to put the system call and the register read into the same inline asm statement.  That's the only way to be sure the compiler hasn't inserted other instructions in between.

Comment: Or just put the system call by itself in an inline asm statement, and have output operands with the "b", "c", "d" constraints.  Then the compiler will generate the `mov`s for you, or just use the values in place if it can.

Comment: @NateEldredge: This code *is* the implementation of a system call; note that it's using `printk`.  So it's probably running inside the Linux kernel and could (on older Linux) run with register values that match what user-space had before a `syscall` instruction.  More recent Linux sanitizes registers, presumably to help guard against `jmp reg` sequences as Spectre gadgets.  Note the EBX / RBX is call-preserved, so if code inside this function hasn't changed it then printk won't have.  But it's also the first reg the compiler will pick for data that it wants to keep across function calls.

Comment: So in recent Linux kernels I think syscall implementation functions only get an arg that points to the struct of user-space registers saved on entry to the kernel, and have to reload their args from memory.  With zero details in the question about this even being Linux, let alone what version, and other mistaken assumptions being fundamental showstoppers, not much point saying more.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added to the code syscall, missed it when copy-paste code.
For me is the most important to understand that operation:
__asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%ebx,%0" : "=r"(reg_val[0]));
is doing the same thing as:
__asm__ volatile (
            "\t movl %%ebx,%0" : "=r"(ebx_val));

I mean that to verify they are both writing ebx address correctly, in the first case address is going to the array member, and in the second case register value is going to the variable.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Look at compiler output to see how it compiles to asm, mixing compiler-generated asm with your inline asm, and what registers the compiler picked for asm `"=r"` template operands.  (`gcc -O2 -S`, or on https://godbolt.org/)  That should help you see that the compiler doesn't treat incoming register values as anything, just temporaries it can overwrite inside the function, because in the calling convention they're not.  If you want to care about registers keeping their value throughout your function, you have to write the whole thing in asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes For me is the most important thing is to be sure that registers were scrubbed when returning from the system call.

Comment: It's not going to change EBX; as I said it's call-preserved.  Any function call may clobber ECX and EDX, though.  Not that this random inline asm will reliably detect that; you need to write a caller in asm so you can see ECX and EDX as "outputs" of a function despite the calling convention not doing that..  This is inside the kernel, right? If not, if it's an actual inline system call made from user-space, then 32-bit `int 0x80` preserves all 32-bit regs except EAX, or 64-bit `syscall` preserves everything except RAX, RCX, and R11.

Comment: @PeterCordes Inside the kernel is running only system call, that function is running in user mode.

Comment: How is `test_syscall()` defined?  It shouldn't modify any user-space registers if it's just a wrapper around `int 0x80`.  And why are you using a function called `printk` in user-space code?  I've only seen that name used in the Linux kernel so it's very misleading to see it in user-space code.